# I need use Javascript to read a COM port

Tags: javascript

I need to read a value from a **serial port (COM)** with **javascript** to use in a web component.

The objetive is integrate this web component in a pluggin to **business central 17 OnPremise** so a page could read the value (integer) provided by a hardware conected to the client.

Does anyone have an idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript I assume client-side javascript, which is not possible.

One approach would be to create a server, for example in NodeJS which will run on the machine where the hardware is located. That server should read the data from COM port and output it over http interface.

That way, on your page, you could read data via ajax.

Comment: Yes, the script that I need is for client-side.